# Javascript Ignore certain list items on key up / down

Tags: javascript

is it possible to skip certain list items based on their class on key up or key down.

for example the results of an autocomplete box like:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="heading">Some heading</li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li class="heading">Another heading</li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
</ul>
```

on key up or down I would like anything with a class of heading to be skipped over.

Comment: What does `skipped over on key up or down` means?? Which key? skipped over means does not show??

Comment: well how are you moving it currently?

Answer (score 0):

Create an action keyboard listener which will keep track of the key up and key down event and inside the function you can toggle the behavior of the required tags by assigning it to a class having setVisible = false 
So whenever you find a class with heading the visibility will be set to false.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of what you want. I hope this helps you.

```js
function hideElements() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.heading'), function(el) {
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  });
  isVisible = false;
}

function showElements() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.heading'), function(el) {
    el.style.visibility = 'visible';
  });
  isVisible = true;
}

var isVisible = true;

var myBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');

//add event listener
myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (isVisible) {
    hideElements();
    isVisible = false;
  } else {
    showElements();
    isVisible = true;
  }
});
```

```html
 On key down <b>heading</b> classes will be hidden and on key up they will be visible:
 <br />
 
 <input type="text" onkeyup="showElements()" onkeydown="hideElements()"> 

<ul>
  <li class="heading">Some heading</li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li class="heading">Another heading</li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A result</a></li>
</ul>

This button toggle view of classes also.<br />
<button id="toggle">Toggle heading</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you want a select box with disabled options, this way when using the up and down keys to browse through the list it will skip disabled choices:

```html
<select>
  <option class="heading" disabled>A Choices</option>
  <option><a href="#">A-1</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">A-2</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">A-3</a></option>
  <option class="heading" disabled>B Choices</option>
  <option><a href="#">B-1</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">B-2</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">B-3</a></option>
</select>
```

This can also be done programatically by adding the `disabled` attribute.

```js
function disableHeadings(){
  var headings = document.getElementsByClassName("heading");
  for(var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++){
    headings[i].setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute("disabled"));
  }
}

disableHeadings();
```

```html
<select>
  <option class="heading">A Choices</option>
  <option selected><a href="#">A-1</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">A-2</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">A-3</a></option>
  <option class="heading">B Choices</option>
  <option><a href="#">B-1</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">B-2</a></option>
  <option><a href="#">B-3</a></option>
</select>
```